# How to write to print string variable and a looped range variable together in one line

Tags: python

Am trying to loop through a range of variables and write them to output files on new lines.

I have researched and tried f.write, print(), printf, and f'.

Code is returning frequent syntax error or i am passing too many arguments or cannot concatenate strings and integers.

DEFINE VARIABLES

`House = range(0,40,10)` .

LOOP THROUGH EACH VARIATION:

```
casenumber = 0 #used in the filename
for ham in House:

                # CREATE INDIVIDUAL YML (TEXT) FILES
                casenumber = casenumber + 1
                filename = 'Case%.3d.yml' % casenumber
                f = open(filename, 'w')
                # The content of the file:

                f.write('My House has this many cans of spam', House)

                f.close()
```

Comment: The `House` in `f.write('My House has this many cans of spam', House)` should probably be `ham`
Also `File.write` only takes one argument, so you should split this in multiple calls to `f.write`.

Comment: Don't need to split calls to `f.write()`, just need to use `str.format()` or `f-string`. I think OP expects `f.write()` to behave same as `print('something value is', something)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you, I think you want to write the number `ham` to the file

```
casenumber = 0 #used in the filename

#Iterate through the range
for ham in range(0,40,10):

    # CREATE INDIVIDUAL YML (TEXT) FILES
    casenumber = casenumber + 1
    filename = 'Case%.3d.yml' % casenumber
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    # The content of the file:

    #I assume you want to write the value of ham in the file
    f.write('My House has this many cans of spam {}'.format(ham))

    f.close()
```

We will get 4 files here with the content in front of them

```
Case001.yml #My House has this many cans of spam 0
Case002.yml #My House has this many cans of spam 10
Case003.yml #My House has this many cans of spam 20
Case004.yml #My House has this many cans of spam 30
```

In addition, you can also use `with` statement to open your file, which will take care of closing your file for you as below.

```
casenumber = 0 #used in the filename

#Iterate through the range
for ham in range(0,40,10):

    # CREATE INDIVIDUAL YML (TEXT) FILES
    casenumber = casenumber + 1
    filename = 'Case%.3d.yml' % casenumber
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:

        # The content of the file:
        #I assume you want to write the value of ham in the file
        f.write('My House has this many cans of spam {}'.format(ham))
```